# logic and discrete mathematics

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

Could someone please explain the solution of this question to me?

The question:
  How long would it approximately take to find out whether a formula with 90 different atomic
formulas is a tautology? You may assume it takes 1 ns to evaluate the formula on a single
truth assignment.

Solution:
  There are 2^90 ≈ 10^30 possible assignments, so it takes approximately 10^30 ns ≈ 10^16 days≈10^12 years.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. You should try one of the other sites on StackExchange. (Maybe start [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/))

Answer (score 0):

The question assumes that you are checking every possible combination of the 90 truth variables. This means that you have 90 variables, each of them either `true` or `false` or in other words `1` or `0`. Imagine all 90 variables written down as zeros and ones in a row. This corresponds to a 90 digit binary number. Trying out every combination of truth values now amounts to trying out every 90 digit binary number. This is the same as counting from `0` to `2^90 - 1` which gives you `2^90` possible combinations.

Now `2^10 = 1024` is approximately `1000 = 10^3`, so `2^90 ≈ 10^30`.